# iTunes Connect > "Submit for Review" button is disabled?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I prepared everything as normal, but the "Submit for Review" button is always disabled. Is that intended during holiday?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even I am facing the same.

As displayed on AppStoreConnect,

App Store Connect Holiday Schedule: Dec 23–27
Make sure your apps are up to date and ready for the holidays. New apps and app updates will not be accepted December 23 to 27 (Pacific Time), so any releases should be submitted, approved, and scheduled in advance. Other App Store Connect and developer account features will remain available.

Comment: I think they should mention this in the message. Disable the button is not a good idea.

Comment: **so any releases should be submitted, approved, and scheduled in advance**, I think this says it.

Comment: Also this, **New apps and app updates will not be accepted December 23 to 27 (Pacific Time)**

Answer (score 0):

It's Christmas change freeze **App Store Connect Holiday Schedule: Dec 23–27**. Even ipa is still Processing stage as well after being uploaded.

Comment: my ipa is processed successfully after upload.

Comment: but my one is still on **processing** since today morning.